# Constraint relations question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Here's a common Newtonian mechanics problem.

Assume conditions to be ideal - pulley is massless, frictionless, strings are inextensible. Two blocks A and B are moving down with a constant speed $u$. We have to find the upward speed of block C when the strings make an angle of theta with the vertical.

[image]

My approach:
We know that $θ$ is not constant. Let, the distance of P below the level of the pulleys be $l\cosθ$ where $l$ is the length of string between point P and one of the pulleys. So,

$$ v=-\frac{d}{dt}(lcosθ)=\frac{−dl}{dt}cosθ+lsinθ\frac{dθ}{dt}=ucosθ+lsinθ\frac{dθ}{dt}.  $$

I am stuck after this, as to how to calculate $\frac{dθ}{dt}$.

The final answer given in the book is $ v=\frac{u}{cosθ} $ and now if I reverse calculate  $\frac{dθ}{dt}$, then $\frac{dθ}{dt}=\frac{v}{l}sinθ $ but how do we calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What’s unchanging is the horizontal distance from the vertical axis of P to either pulleys’ vertical axis. I’ll denote it as d. Then you can relate $\theta$ to $l$ by the relation $l=\frac{d}{\sin\theta}$. The rest should follow after differentiating both sides and since $\frac{dl}{dt} = -u$ as you have noticed.

Comment: Thank you so much! by differentiating $l=\frac{d}{\sin\theta}$ , we get $\frac{dθ}{dt}=\frac{u}{l}tanθ $, which helps get the result $ v=\frac{u}{cosθ} $. But, do you know, how can we get $\frac{dθ}{dt}=\frac{v}{l}sinθ $ ? This also leads to the same answer.

Comment: @AditiBansal I got $\frac{u}{l}\tan\theta$ after reverse calculating, I don't know how you got the answer with the $\sin\theta$ term.